# How to keep a command output window in vim

Tags: vim

What I'm looking for is a different window than the current one containing the output of a command into the same buffer. So I can execute:

```
:!php %
```

And see the output in a bottom split window. That's commonly seen in most graphical editors I've used.

Notes:

1. Not the current window. Don't want to have to switch back
2. Not creating a new buffer each time. (have to reuse "output" buffer)
3. I don't want that in a register, I want to be able to see the output straight away.

The flow would be:

1. Open vim -S session ...
2. Edit a file
3. Execute a simple make-type command
4. Look at command output in output window

*without* having hundreds of new buffers and having to switch between windows.

What I've tried so far that is not satisfactory ... sending output to file, turning autoread on, opening a buffer on that file. That works but I have to turn autoread on for all files.. a bit annoying. Is there a way to turn autoread for a single buffer/file?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 9):

It sounds like you are looking for Vim's "[**quickfix**](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html#quickfix)" window. I'd use [`'makeprg'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27makeprg%27), [`:make`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html#:make) and [`:copen`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html#:copen), like this:

```
:set makeprg=php\ %
:make
:copen
```

---

Additionally, you can use the [`'errorformat'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27errorformat%27) option to deliver the cursor to the first line containing an error.

```
:set errorformat=%m\ in\ %f\ on\ line\ %l
```

And for speed, I have <kbd>F5</kbd> mapped to `make`:

```
:nnoremap <F5> :<C-U>make<CR>
```

Comment: Note that (like any other external command invocation in vim) this runs the command synchronously i.e. vim blocks until the command has finished.